# Referring to a Set of Objects

Tags: multiplicity

I have a box of plastic fantasy miniatures with title "Orcs" on it. If I take a figure out, how do I refer where it comes from?

1. From the plastic **Orcs** boxed set, or
2. From the plastic **Orc** boxed set

Which is correct?

Comment: I would say that it was "from the boxed set of plastic Orcs" myself because it comes from the boxed set which happens to be a set of plastic Orcs.

Comment: Or simply 'from the box labelled _Orcs_.'

Comment: 'From the plastic Orc boxed set' and 'From the plastic Orcs boxed set' are not ungrammatical. The first corresponds to the rule-of-thumb _attributive nouns/noun groups are usually used in the singular form_ (thus rabbit skins, steering wheel covers ...). The second may be chosen to emphasise that there is more than one orc in the set (it _could_ contain 1 orc + accessories!). **But** almost everybody would say 'from the boxed set of plastic Orcs', like BBen and myself, so it's the idiomatic (democratic) choice.